# MySQL - query where Order By doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm expecting the resulting "user_id" to be the one corresponding to the 1st records in the Location table in DESCending order.
But I am getting the "user_id" of the 1st record in ASCending order / or ID order.

```
SELECT Device.name, Location.user_id
  FROM    locations Location
       LEFT JOIN devices Device
            ON Device.id = Location.device_id
 WHERE Device.id IN (491)
GROUP BY Location.device_id
ORDER BY Location.location_datetime DESC
```

Anyone know why?
How to improve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. Here's a link that explains why: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html. In particular you should read this bit: `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.`

Comment: Why are you grouping with `Location.device_id` and selecting  `Device.name, Location.user_id`? and why not `ORDER BY user_id` instead? Can you please explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Mark - I see!  I guessed as much.

Comment: Mahmoud - because I want latest user_id per device in the IN clause, there could be many devices in the IN clause

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  devices.name,
  (select locations.user_id
   from locations
   where locations.device_id = devices.id
   order by locations.location_datetime desc
   limit 1)
FROM
  devices
WHERE
  device.id = 491
```

you can't use `group by` with nonaggregated columns to get the first or the last record: it is not guaranteed that it will always work.

**EDIT:** if you need to select more than one field from locations, you could use this:

```
SELECT l1.*, devices.name
FROM
  locations l1 inner join
  (select device_id, max(location_datetime) as maxdt
   from locations
   group by device_id) l2
  on l1.device_id = l2.device_id and l1.location_datetime=l2.maxdt
  left join devices
  on devices.id = l1.device_id
```

this query will select last location for each device_id. If there are more than one location with the same maximum datetime, this query will return each one. If you need just one, and don't mind which one is selected, you could also add a `GROUP BY l1.device_id` clause at the end.

Comment: This works thanks!  There are other fields that I want from locations as well, such as the latest location_datetime.  So I need to keep the outer clause as well for that purposes.

Comment: @iss42 i updated my answer... if you need to select more fields from locations think you need something like my second query.. let me know if it's this what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      SELECT Device.name, Location.user_id ,Location.location_datetime
      FROM    locations Location
      LEFT JOIN devices Device
        ON Device.id = Location.device_id
     WHERE Device.id IN (491)

    ORDER BY Location.user_id DESC
    GROUP BY Location.device_id
```